# how can i use processing and swing in the same class.?

Tags: java, swing, processing

so i made a class usibg processing aplet :
public class EarthquakeCityMap extends PApplet implements ActionListener {
but i had to add textfield which i cant add in processing so i decide to use swing :

```
private void addSearchButton() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //setLayout(null) ;

    fill(255,255,255) ;
    textSize(14);
    text("country : ",3, 325) ;
    text ("magnitude : ",3 , 475) ;
    text ("depth  : ", 3, 625) ;

    setVisible(true) ;
    setLayout(null) ;

    dane1 = new JTextField() ;
    dane1.setBounds(80,325,250,20);
    add(dane1) ;


    dane2 = new JTextField() ;
    dane2.setBounds(80,355,250,20);
    add(dane2) ;

    dane3 = new JTextField() ;
    dane3.setBounds(80,375,250,20);
    add(dane3) ;


    JButton gotowy = new JButton ("Szukaj") ;
    gotowy.setBounds(80,405,250,20);
    gotowy.addActionListener(this);
    add(gotowy) ;



}
```

but that doesnt work the textfields dont show. Pliss help. Im doing that for a month. And still cant solve it.

Comment: From the [JavaDocs for `PApplet`](https://processing.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/processing/build/javadoc/core/processing/core/PApplet.html) - *"Note that you should not use AWT or Swing components inside a Processing apple"*

Comment: From the same [JavaDocs](https://processing.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/processing/build/javadoc/core/processing/core/PApplet.html): _"Because AWT and Swing GUI components cannot be used on top of a PApplet, you can instead embed the PApplet inside another GUI the way you would any other Component."_

Answer (score 1):

You can't put Swing or AWT inside Processing.

You can put Processing inside Swing or AWT (or JavaFX), but that's a bit more difficult- since Processing 3, `PApplet` no longer extends `Applet`.

Your best bets are probably to either create an entirely-Swing `JFrame` which you can pop up from your Processing sketch, or to use a Processing gui library listed on the [Processing libraries](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/) page.